# How to enter $_POST data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1" from the following code:

```
function rememberData($_POST) {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $_SESSION;
}
```

Above is how I stored $_POST into $_SESSION. I call the method on a different page. Just posting it to show the process.

```
$columns = implode(",", array_keys($_SESSION));
$values = implode(",", array_values($_SESSION));

$sql = "INSERT INTO table ($columns) VALUES ('$values')";
// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {
  echo "$key column was added";
} else {
  echo "Error adding columns: " . mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

I stored all of the $_POST data from a form into $_SESSION using a foreach. The data matches up perfectly with the keys when I var_dump the session. I understand this is not secure but its not important. Does anyone know why I am continuing to get this MYSQL error?

Edit: Added how I set up $_SESSION. I'm doing this so I have access to the POST data for multiple pages.

Edit 2: The below tells me that I have a syntax error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"name","Date0","Day0","UnitHours0","ProjectHours0","QwestMark0","TotalTickets0",' at line 1

So I thought it was the single quotes at the beginning and end but if I trim those they dont go away. It must be just the browser displaying the info? There are no single quotes anywhere in my code. Which is confirmed by var_dump.

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    $columns .= "\"$key\"" . ",";
    $values .= "\"$value\"" . ",";
}
$columns = rtrim($columns, ",");
$values = rtrim($values, ",");

echo $sql = "INSERT INTO tables ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
// Execute query
if (mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {
  echo "$key column was added";
} else {
  echo mysqli_error($connection);
}
```

Comment: `'$values'` has some extra characters it shouldn't have - can you guess what they are?

Comment: `$_SESSION` may be you want to use some think like this `$_SESSION['name']` its just a guess, post the code where you are setting your session. guesses normally dont work. Thanks

Comment: Why not echo your `$sql` and see how many columns and values it has?

Comment: I really cannot guess any more. I am at a point where I have been staring at it so long that my brain has melted. I'm sure its going to be obvious once someone tells me why...Basically I have a form with 77 entry points that I am just trying to dump into one line in the mysql database.

Comment: You never call `rememberData`.... Is it possible you're value contains something like `','`. Looks you perform some kind of *sql injection*...

Comment: I know it happens on a different page. Someone had asked how I stored the data into $_SESSION so I showed the function...Yes $value does contain "," but isn't that how SQL will know which column to add the value to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you quote the keys, it should be backticks if anything.

For the values double quotes is fine, single are more common though:

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
    $columns .= "`$key`" . ",";
    $values .= "'$value'" . ",";
}
```

As for preparing the query its not just for security, if you have bad characters (such as single quote) it will break the query so at least use `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: This fixed it! Do you know why the double quotes were causing the issue vs the backticks?

Comment: because you dont quote column names only values, and that is required  if they are varchar type. the ticks will just avoid reserved keyword issues

Comment: @user275667 Awesome, you accepted the answer that said exactly what I was trying to explain you for almost an hour...

Comment: @Shomz you were saying that the $values had rogue single quotes somewhere which was not the problem. SQL was complaining because of the answer I selected. The problem was the quotes around the $keys.

Comment: If you don't quote every single value (like I said about million times), it won't work... Try removing the values part of meda's answer and you'll see.

Comment: Right I get that part which is what I had changed under edit 2. However that didn't solve the problem because SQL was still complaining about the quotes in $columns.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the whole $values into quotes, making it a single string while instead **each of its values should be a separate string**.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table ($columns) VALUES ('$values')";
                                             ^  here ^
```

This renders into, for example:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table ('column1', 'column2') VALUES ('value1, value2')";
```

meaning that the value for the first column is `'value1, value2'` and there's no value for the second column. Instead, it should look like:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table ('column1', 'column2') VALUES ('value1', 'value2')";
```

---

Because of this, your code will work only if the $_SESSION has one or no elements.

Comment: If I remove those I get this: Error adding columns: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: You probably didn't wrap **each** value into quotes put pasted them raw.

Comment: No, it's not fine, the whole thing is still wrapped in single quotes: `'"name", `... Why don't you echo the full $sql variable and I'll show you what's wrong.

Comment: I have done that. There is no single quotes anywhere...This is what the browser shows me at the exact spot its saying to look: INSERT INTO tables ("name","Date0","Day0","UnitHours0","ProjectHours0","QwestMark0","TotalTickets0",

Comment: The columns are not the issue (they can be unquoted or backticked instead) but the values...